# Select one row where startdate & enddate come from first and last row by group

Tags: r, database, data.table

I don't usually work in R but for this I have to and I have no idea how to start.

My data looks this:

```
sample <- data.table(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), score = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 30, 30), 
       start = c("26/03/2018 14:54:26", "27/04/2018 15:34:27", "05/05/2018 22:25:39", "05/05/2018 22:36:18", "26/04/2018 14:54:26", "27/04/2018 15:34:27") ,
       end = c("27/04/2018 15:30:38", "05/05/2018 22:21:31", "05/05/2018 22:31:20", "", "27/04/2018 15:30:38", ""))
```

And I want one line for each unique ID and value combination, where start is the first startdate of the value for this ID and end the last enddate of this value for the ID. The result would look like this:

```
sample2 <- data.table(ID = c("A", "A", "B"), score = c(1, 2,30), 
                 start = c("26/03/2018 14:54:26", "05/05/2018 22:36:18", "26/04/2018 14:54:26") ,
                 end = c( "05/05/2018 22:31:20", "",  ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in sequential order you could simply do:

```
sample[, .(start = first(start), end = last(end)),  by = .(ID, score)]

   ID score               start                 end
1:  A     1 26/03/2018 14:54:26 05/05/2018 22:31:20
2:  A     2 05/05/2018 22:36:18                    
3:  B    30 26/04/2018 14:54:26
```

Or more concisely:

```
sample[, .(start = start[1L], end = end[.N]),  by = .(ID, score)]
```